# Metamask/Web3 integration is breaking my Reactjs App on Mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, metamask, ethers.js

I have a page in my react app:

```
<Route path="thePage" element={<thePage />} />
```

This works fine in desktop responsive mode, but it breaks my whole website when I access it from my safari/chrome apps on mobile (it works on metamask browser).

I would like to remove this from routes, and render it as an external link. How can this be done?

I have tried creating a link to

```
"https://localhost:5174/thePage",
```

and in the component:

```
const location = useLocation();
  const [render, setRender] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    location.pathname() == "/thePage" ? setRender(true) : setRender(false);
  }, [location]);
```

but no luck here, kind of a hacky solution so I'm not surprised. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is breaking? It would likely be easier to do a mobile browser check and either conditionally render the route, or do render the route and conditionally call whatever is breaking in the routed component. I don't know what "metamask browser" is, but just because it works there doesn't mean it will work in mainstream browsers.

Comment: @DrewReese, the page doesnt load- react doesnt render anything. When people access this website through the browser inside the metamask app, it works fine. The error occurs when the website is accessed on safari and chrome apps, which don't support web3 i suppose. I have just tried conditionally rendering, but the website still isn't loading, not sure why

Comment: I see. You might consider implementing an error boundary around the components using web3 so if users access the app in unsupported browsers that the app doesn't just completely fall over and you can provide *some* meaningful content/message to the user.